# How to connect to WiFi from Ubuntu Command Line Shell

Tags: networking

I am having problems with my Ubuntu partition, and need a bit of kind help.

I am trying to reinstall `ubuntu-desktop` and a few other packages, but I cannot connect to the WiFi in order to do so.

All Google searches result in using `ifconfig`, which is fine, but apparently it's not installed on my system for some reason.

So, when I do more searches, they say to just install ifconfig, which I cannot do because I'm not connected to a network.

All I want to do is simply connect to the wifi. Surely this must be possible?

Thank you in advance for your kind help.

Comment: see `man nmcli` `nmcli device wifi list` `nmcli device wifi connect <SSID>`

Comment: PRATAP Thanks, I took a look, but there are tons of options and I can't make head or tail of it. I could not find the connect command. I am by no means a sysadmin or a programmer, and one could not call me knowledgable when it comes to computers or Linux by any means. Could you perhaps by more specific? Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after finding out from PRATAP that the command I need to be using is `nmcli`, I did some Googling and typed in the command: `nmcli d wifi connect MYNETWORK password PASSWORD` (substituting MYNETWORK for the ssid of the wifi and PASSWORD for the wifi password) and it worked! I'm connected!